# How can I pass a string, or list of function names to be processed as callbacks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Done a bit of Googling, but not quite finding what I want.

In an effort to reduce the amount of JAvascript lines my applications requires, I am trying to use as many reusable functions as possible.

The problem of course is trying to make these functions and flexible as possible.

So I have a form which is dynamically expanded by a cloning function using jQuery. In order for this to work, there are a few additional functions which need to run, for example, to correctly initialise datepickers, on the dynamically created elements.

These requirements are different depending upon which form is being cloned.

So, I call my cloning function as follows:

```
$('.button').click(function (){
    var thisID = $(this).attr('id').replace('add', '');
    cloneDetails(thisID, initialiseDates);
});
```

The cloneDetails function looks like this:

```
function cloneDetails(cur_num, callBackFunctions) {

  /// do loads of stuff ///

 callBackFunctions();

});
```

In this instance, the cloning function will run and do what it needs, then it'll run a second function call `initialiseDates`

What I want to be able to do though is specify several function names to run after the cloning function, with a call such as

```
cloneDetails(thisID, 'initialiseDates, doSomethingElse, doAnotherThing');
```

So, stating a list of functions to run after the cloneDetails function has been run.

I don't think I am setting up the callBack method correctly, and don't know how I should be.

Help much appreciated.

EDIT: I don't want to bundle all these functions into a single function, the whole point is these functions should all be useable independently and/or together.

Comment: You can pass array of functions. [initialiseDates, doSomethingElse,...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of several approaches:

1. You can split the string and use `eval(name+'()')` in each name in the list. Note that `eval()` can be evil, security wise.
2. Instead of a string, why not pass the functions as an array? Simply iterate over `arguments[1..n]` (`arguments` is an automatic variable which contains all function arguments).
3. Use an anonymous function:

   ```
   cloneDetails(thisID, function(){
       initialiseDates();
       doSomethingElse();
       doAnotherThing();
   });
   ```

I like the last approach because:

1. It's the most flexible
2. Readable
3. Only adds a few bytes of code where you need them
4. Most performant

Comment: Yes, option 3 is exactly what I wasn't sure how to do!
Only thing is, for some reason my initialiseDates function won't actually work like that! Others do, but the dates thing is pretty universally applicable so I've just included it in the clone function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option (if you're using jQuery > 1.7): You can use the [jQuery.Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/) function.

```
cloneDetails(thisID, $.Callbacks()
    .add(initialiseDates, doSomethingElse, doAnotherThing));

function cloneDetails(cur_num, callBackFunctions) {

  /// do loads of stuff ///

  callBackFunctions.fire();

});
```